# Jquery ajax call with asp.net routing implemented

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm using asp.net forms and i implemented asp.net routing and now my standard ajax calls don't work.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:45027/Users/UserData.aspx/GetData",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //do something with data
        },
        error: function (textStatus) {

        }
    });
```

but now my url is not http://localhost:45027/Users/UserData.aspx but it is http://localhost:45027/UserSettings and my ajax calls don't work anymore... I found some answers but all are related to MVC and i couldn't implement them in my application.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:45027/UserSettings/GetData`? Not sure it would work, but it might be worth stating if you did, or trying if you haven't.

Comment: i did try it and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

have you tried requesting the same url in your browser? All an $.ajax POST is doing is making that request as a Form post.  Since you have nothing in your data: parameter, maybe it should be a GET request?